# AVFoundation video preview is darker than the native Camera app

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation to produce video frames.
The problem is that the frames look darker than in the native camera app, especially in dark areas.

As I see, the native camera app (iOS 8) makes some adjustments (ISO, shutter speed) all the time and continuously adopts itself to the environment light conditions (it seems that in low-light conditions it slows the shutter speed, rather then increasing the ISO).

I cannot make my video preview looks the same. Tried settings the exposure mode to AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure, but it does not make the same effect.

Please advise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IOS 8 introduced a number of improvements to image capture and I don't doubt that the native app isn't leaning on a number of them.

If you have access [this Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014578) exposes all of the new features (white balance, ISO, shutter speed etc).

You will need to combine a few of these settings to replicate the built in - auto exposure alone is unlikely to match the built in.

Comment: Thanks! Will look at it, but do you know based on what parameters I can change the shutter speed on? How do I "know" there is low light condition on the scene?

Comment: Maybe I need to use exposureTargetOffset value of AVCaptureDevice somehow?

Comment: There is a white balance grey setting if I recall correctly where you can point the camera at a printed card to calibrate. It isn't exactly practical, but lighting differs between environments so there is only so much preconfigured settings can achieve.

Answer (score 5):

Well the above answer is 100% correct. In my case though, i was setting AVCaptureSession property sessionPreset to AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh and the preview was a lot darker than the one in camera app. When I changed this preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto the preview looked so much better and didn't seem to be as dark as before... Maybe it's just this setting.